# How to programmatically open an application by name on macOS?

Tags: python, macos

I'm writing a cross-platform Python application that acts as a frontend for [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki). It needs to call the DOSBox executable with a number of command line arguments. I don't want to hardcode a specific path to DOSBox because it might depend on where the user has installed it.

On Linux, I can simply do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['dosbox'] + args)
```

On macOS, however, I currently use the following code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['/Applications/dosbox.app/Contents/MacOS/DOSBox'] + args)
```

Which seems awfully specific and I'm not even sure whether it works, since I don't have a mac to test on.

What is the correct way to open an application *by name* on macOS?

(NB: I have also asked this [sibling question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65520398/) for Windows.)

Comment: `subprocess.call(['open','Path/To/Application'])`

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified the question

Comment: Since you rely on the application being on PATH on Linux, why not do the same on Mac?

Comment: Because unlike Linux, `dosbox` does not get added to the `PATH` on macOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know **DOSBox** or want it on my Mac, but in general, when you install an application on macOS it has a *"property list"* file, or `plist` or `"info.plist"` in it. In there, the developer is supposed to put a *"bundle identifier"* key called `CFBundleIdentifier`. This must be unique across all applications, so for **DOSBox** it should be something like:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.dosboxinc.dosbox</string>
```

Get one of your users to find that, then you can use the bundle identifier to open it like this regardless of installation location:

```
open -b BUNDLEIDENTIFIER --args arg1 arg2 arg3
```

where `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` get passed on to **DOSBox**.

---

You *may* be able to get the bundle identifier by running this in **Terminal**:

```
osascript -e 'id of app "DOSBox"'
```

Note, however, that if this command works, it means I have correctly guessed the app name `"DOSBox"`, which means that you could just use the app name with `open`, rather than the bundle identifier like this:

```
open -a DOSBox --args arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Would you (or anyone else) be so kind to install DOSBox for a moment just to check if the `open -a DOSBox` command works?

Answer (score 0):

Most applications on a Mac are kept in /Applications, so /Applications/dosbox.app/Contents/MacOS/DOSBox seems like the correct filepath to the executable most of the time to me. I did try installing DOSBox on my Mac and the application is usually called DOSBox.app, however.

It is true that a Mac user could theoretically put the application anywhere, which might mean using os.walk would be the way to find it. I don't know of a way to lookup an application in macOS except by recursive searching, which is how I believe the system itself does it when it needs to. What I would try is using os.path.isfile to check for if the executable exists in the usual location, then searching for it in the directory ~. Directories outside the current user's directory are unlikely to contain this application.

Comment: I don't believe an exhaustive search of the filesystem is the correct answer. There must be a way to search for installed programs only.