# How to programmatically open an application by name on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing a cross-platform Python application that acts as a frontend for [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki). It needs to call the DOSBox executable with a number of command line arguments. I don't want to hardcode a specific path to DOSBox because it might depend on where the user has installed it.

On Linux, I can simply do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['dosbox'] + args)
```

On Windows, however, I currently use the following code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['C:\PROGRAM FILES(X86)\DOSBOX\DOSBOX.EXE'] + args)
```

Which seems awfully specific, and doesn't work if DOSBox is installed in, for instance, the [`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs`](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/what-is-localappdataprograms/a3a349c3-cd93-48d5-acb9-760d4a2f489a) folder. Instead, I'd like to query the registry for the correct entry point to a program that identifies as "DOSBox". How can I do that in Python?

(NB: I have also asked this [sibling question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65516999/) for macOS.)

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to use `winreg` to find where dosbox is installed

I'm basing my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227427/7540911) answer

```
import winreg
reg_conn = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
#  note that i dont have dosbox so you may have to double check the capitalization
key = winreg.OpenKey(reg_conn , r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\DOSBox") 
res_tuple = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'InstallLocation')
```

`res_tuple[0]` should be the directory of where dosbox is installed, but as i've mentioned I do not have it installed so you should double check that `InstallLocation` is the correct key

This will probably not work for the portable version of dosbox because it probably doesnt have any registry keys

Comment: Although this _is_ the correct answer, it doesn't work because there is no `DOSBox` key in the `CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry, even when DOSBox is installed. I guess I'll have to stick to my original approach.

Comment: @hedgie its installed and there are no keys at all? try maybe in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

Comment: Yes, it's installed using the regular installer from dosbox.com